# Does explicitly setting shouldComponentUpdate() to false make the Component “Uncontrolled”?

Tags: reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

An **"Uncontrolled Component"** keeps the "source of truth" in the DOM. So that puts it outside of the Virtual DOM world.
For these Components React will only do the initial render once then ignore it.

If a class with has `shouldComponentUpdate()` set to `false` then React too, will only do the initial renders then ignore it.

So if a class that has `shouldComponentUpdate()` **explicitly** set to `false` does that technically make it a **Uncontrolled Component**?